# Get entire record (Row) for Max value in one column

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, max

I have a table where I have values for different categories on a specific date time. I want to get date time for each category having the max value  .

```
PERIOD_START_TIME   RNC name    Unit Type   AVERAGE_LOAD (M592C0)
11.10.2013 20:00:00 N109        ICSU                70.75
11.09.2013 19:00:00 N109        ICSU                70.25
10.28.2013 00:00:00 N403        ICSU                41.25
10.28.2013 00:00:00 N403        ICSU                51.5
10.28.2013 00:00:00 N403        ICSU                53.75
10.28.2013 00:00:00 N601        ICSU                44.25
10.28.2013 00:00:00 N601        ICSU                44.25
```

I want the Max of AVERAGE_Load for each RNC for whatever the time.

Answer (score 0):

Please note the slighty modified field names

```
SELECT tbl.RNC_name, Max(tbl.AVERAGE_LOAD) AS Max_AVERAGE_LOAD
FROM tbl
GROUP BY tbl.RNC_name;
```

for "tbl" please use the actual table name.

You can use " " in field names if you use "[]" but I prefer not to.

Answer (score 0):

Is your sample data correct? The last two rows are the same. Either you allow duplicates or there are other fields in your table which you are not showing.

You need to group the other fields in one query and then join that back to the original table to get the date/time of the max average load

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.PERIOD_START_TIME,
       Max_T.RNC_name,
       Max_T.Unit_Type,
       Max_T.max_avg_load
FROM T INNER JOIN
     (SELECT RNC_name,
             Unit_Type,
             MAX(AVERAGE_LOAD) AS max_avg_load
      FROM T
      GROUP BY RNC_name,
               Unit_Type) AS Max_T
ON T.RNC_name = Max_T.RNC_name AND
   T.Unit_Type = Max_T.Unit_Type AND
   T.AVERAGE_LOAD = Max_T.max_avg_load
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0aa27/9)